# Focus Listerner for a custom view not triggered first time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv

I have a Custom View class so for the entire view I need to check the focus state to see if if is focussed or not focused.

**What I have tried**

used `setOnFocusChangeListener { }` callback to check focused state.

- The problem here is that this callback is not triggered the first
  time and few other times and behaviour is not consistent in trigerring the callback.
- I have even set focusable=true, focusIntouchMode = true attributes to the view.

Please provide some inputs in case I am missing something here. Thanks

Here's some code

```
   CarouselCardView constructor(context) : CustomWidget(context),ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private var currentPage = 0

override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
    return R.layout.banner
}

init {
    isFocusable = true
    isFocusableInTouchMode = true
}

private fun setViewpagerAutoAdvanceFeature(
    modelData: List<ContentData>
) {
    //Auto scroll logic goes here
}

override fun bindData(modelData: List<ContentData>) {

    val pagerAdapter = HeroPagerAdapter(context, model = modelTV,
        onClickItem = { position ->
            clickListener.onItemSelected(uiComponent, uiComponent.componentItems[position])
        },
        onLastItemReached = { viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true) })
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
}

//Call backs don't trigger 
setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        Log.e("ANI","On setOnFocusChangeListener showing")
    } else {
        Log.e("ANI","On setOnFocusChangeListener not showing")

    }
}
```

Here's the layout for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/heroBanner"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_900"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_380"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_900"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/viewPager"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/btn_selector"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_line_indicator"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which view is using the function `setOnFocusListener`?

Comment: @NullByte08 I have added the layout  please check, so I want it for the entire view in this case. consider heroBanner for the root

Answer (score 0):

I made a custome view and i tried to call setOnFocusChangeListener in view class like what you provided in the question. but after calling setOnFocusChangeListener like

```
setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        Log.e("ANI","On setOnFocusChangeListener showing")
    } else {
        Log.e("ANI","On setOnFocusChangeListener not showing")

    }
}
```

Android studio gives an error and saying "Expecting member declaration". but I could acheive that by implementing OnFocusChangeListener like this

```
class MyView : View, View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    ...

    override fun onFocusChange(v: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your way of adding it, same behaviour for me doesn't work the first time

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18278663/8136868
I think you should implement onfucuschangelistener where you are going to use your view. like buttons that you define their click listeners in activities or fragments (where they are used not where they are defined)